# How can I pass the value of a Spinner to a ListView?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to pass the values that I have defined in a Spinner to a ListView. I mean when you select an item from this spinner shown in the ListView.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int posicion, long arg3) {
    String valor = spinner_datos[posicion].toString();                  
    adapter.add(valor);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the adapter.add(valor);

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int posicion, long arg3) {
    String valor = spinner_datos[posicion].toString(); 
    adapter.add(valor);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //This will notify the adapter to redraw it's views, updating the list so that you can see the changes          
}
```

You don't need to call the `list.setAdapter(adapter);` again

Comment: allright thank u. but the problem is that the app stop when i try running whit that code. so i dont now how to do it, i wanna know if there are another way to do it.

Comment: you should set your `list.setAdapter(adapter);` on your `onCreate` method